# ¿Cómo crear e importar paquetes en Java manualmente?

Tags: java

Sabemos que un IDE te facilita la vida al programar, pero necesito saber cuando se está trabajando con un editor de texto, como crear paquetes. Intenté separar las clases en carpetas y usar las palabras `package` e `import` pero no funciona.

Comment: Lo que preguntas es precisamente como lo estas realizando, que problema tienes, porque no funciona? agrega mas datos de lo que realizas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funciona de la misma manera toma en cuenta que Java es “Sensitive Case”, hay que respetar mayúsculas y minúsculas. No podemos tener en un mismo paquete dos clases con el mismo nombre. Ademas debes asegurarte de si tener instalado Java Software Development Kit para poder compilarlos

package mipaquete;

import matematicas.numeros.Numero;

Te dejo un link en el que realizan un ejercicio en bloc de notas

http://es.wikihow.com/escribir-tu-primer-programa-en--Java

Saludos!!!

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo crear e importar paquetes en Java manualmente?

Lo que preguntas es precisamente como lo estas realizando

Los paquetes los creas en folders, en las clases defines el paquete y para accesar a otras clases usas import, recuerda que el lenguaje Java es [case-sensitive](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitive).

Te recomiendo este [**tutorial: Introducción a la programación Java**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ssa/java/tutorials/j-introtojava1/) , revisa **Definición de paquete**, **Sentencias de importación** y **Declaración de clase**.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas conocer bien como funcionan los paquetes,  y para hacerlo manual necesitas manejar un directorio bien establecido para que al importar un paquete, este coincida con su configuración de directorios real , ejemplo: tienes la carpeta padre: app y dentro tienes un archivo java: TestPakages.java así como una clase dentro de esta configuración de directorios com/swits/resource/ClaseA.java, (es decir la clase:ClaseA.java esta dentro de la carpeta resource y a su vez resource dentro de swits y swits dentro de com), dentro de la clase: ClaseA.java específicas en la primer linea antes de la declaración del cuerpo de la clase: package com.swits.resource; es decir el mapeo de la clase para acceder a ella, y ya en la clase: TestPakages.java hacemos la importación de la clase como import com.swits.resources.ClaseA; 
Ya solo queda que tus invocaciones a clases coincidan con la configuración real de los directorios .